# PHP fopen backup variable

Tags: php, fopen

Why this isn't working?

```
$handle = fopen([file_patch], "r");
$handle_backup = $handle;

while (($line = fgets($handle)) {...}
$handle = $handle_backup;
while (($line = fgets($handle)) {...}
```

second loop isn't working becouse $handle is NULL.

Comment: both handlers refer to the same obj in memory.

Comment: i do not want to use fopen always when i need something from the same file. Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the official [`fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) documentation:

> fopen() binds a named resource, specified by filename, to a stream.

Which basically means that in your code `$handle` and `$handle_backup` are not distinct items, but rather publicly accessible references to the same resource. Meaning, `$handle` and `$handle_backup` are 100% the same; they are just really different aliases to the same content in memory.

So when you do `fgets($handle)` the file in memory is being acted on so `$handle` and `$handle_backup` will reflect the same result of that action.

Which is all to say that if you are trying to simply open the file once and keep a “backup” to refer to it again, that won’t work since the resource opened has already been acted on.  The only way to have a “backup” as you are describing would be to do this:

```
$handle = fopen([file_patch], "r");
$handle_backup = fopen([file_patch], "r");
```

And that may be useful—or useless—depending on your overall code’s goal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try :

```
$handle1 = fopen([file_patch], "r");
$handle2 = fopen([file_patch], "r");

while (($line1 = fgets($handle1)) {...}
while (($line2 = fgets($handle2)) {...}
```